# Problems with iPad rapid touches, when using jQuery animate and scrollTop()

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios

I am building a user interface for a web app.

The structure is something [like this.](https://jsfiddle.net/bwsmihai/nrofdzLy/)

```
    $("#scroll-down").on("click", function() {
  thumbnails.stop(true, true).animate({
    scrollTop: '+=300'
  }, 100);
```

I'm using two scroll buttons to scroll up and down a div, because the items in the div are draggable, and if you try to scroll by swiping it just picks up a thumbnail instead of scrolling.

The approach I'm using works perfectly on the desktop and on android.
On iOS (specifically iPad with chrome or safari) i have this weird problem that when the user is inpatient and taps fast multiple times on the scroll buttons, the scroll doesn't work responsively (ie: 10 taps on the down button don't take you to the bottom). Almost like the **stop()** doesn't work.

Any ideeas / suggestions?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i figured out the answer and its kind of silly, I had the event listener for click (tap in case of iPad). When rapid clicking on desktop it would work - chrome took them as multiple clicks. But when rapid tapping on iPad - iOS (or Safari) took them as double taps, so they wouldn't trigger my events properly. Made the listener to be for 'click dblclick' and that solved the issue.

Here it is for other people who might find themselves in the same situation:

```
    $("#scroll-down").on("click dblclick", function() {
      thumbnails.stop(true, true).animate({
      scrollTop: '+=300'
    }, 100);
```